# Cisco IP Fragments ACL strange behavior

Tags: cisco, firewall, acl, fragmentation

I am testing following ACL on Cisco 3850 L3 switch :

```
C3850#show ip access-lists 101
Extended IP access list 101
    10 deny ip any any fragments
    20 permit ip any any (268 matches)
```

I applied access list on ISP side interface `in`:

```
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
 description ISP
 no switchport
 ip address 61.XX.XX.158 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group 101 in
```

From remote host, I am doing ping with `-s 1500` big packet size so it will get fragments, and the ACL will drop them. It looks like it works, too; I am not getting ping reply back.

To make sure routing dropping packet or not, I ran `tcpdump` on one of HOST machines, and I can see `ICMP` packets coming in. It's strange why the router is not dropping them at `inbound` ?

The ACL hit count is zero for fragments:

```
C3850#show ip access-lists 101
Extended IP access list 101
    10 deny ip any any fragments
    20 permit ip any any (4006 matches)
```

Comment: Try to do a ping with something really large, like `20000`.

Comment: i tried `-s 20000` and still i am seeing on host packet coming in and on ACL no hitcount

Comment: I see. You are not denying ICMP fragments, Instead of `deny ip any any fragments` use `deny icmp any any fragments`.

Comment: Really? i think `ip` will include all L3 packets..

Comment: IP and ICMP have a special relationship. Just try it to see if it works.

Comment: Did quick test `10 deny icmp any any fragments`  no luck still i am seeing packets coming to HOST machine.. and no HIT on ACL..

Comment: Interesting same TEST i did on GNS3 sim and it works! i can see ACL hit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39683/discussion-between-satish-and-ron-maupin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this will treat an initial fragment the same as a non-fragment. The initial fragment will get through, but subsequent fragments in the same packet will be dropped.

See [Access Control Lists and IP Fragments](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/8014-acl-wp.html):

> ### ACL Rules Flowchart
>
> The following flowchart illustrates the ACL rules when non-fragments,
>   initial fragments, and non-initial fragments are checked against the
>   ACL.
>
> **Note:** The non-initial fragments themselves contain only Layer 3, never Layer 4 information, although the ACL may contain both Layer 3
>   and Layer 4 information.
>
> [image]